# Can we install IBM Worklight 5.0 in IBM Rational Software Architect v8.0 ? If yes, please guide or provide a reference link

Tags: rational-rsa, ibm-mobilefirst

Appreciate your help or any references to do the same.

Also if anyone has installed IBM Worklight to work with Spring Tool Suite.

Answer (score 1):

IBM Worklight Studio is not supported to install into RSA 8.0.x, only on RSA 8.5.x or later. Note that the co-install (aka "shell-sharing") is only supported via Installation Manager. So the developer edition of the Studio, which is the free version available on the eclipse marketplace, can not be installed into RSA 8.5. You have to buy a paid edition of Worklight which will include an IM installer for Studio.

also note there are limitations to shell-sharing. refer to this white paper for details: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/download/attachments/113606723/mobile.dev.white.paper.pdf